# Помогите составить простое регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, match

Нужно только буквы и возможно цифры после букв убрать.
Строка: 644.99 USD PM
Оставить только: 644.99
числа могут быть и через пробел типа 10 100.69
Поэтому выдрать чисто число не выйдет
Вместо USD PM может быть Приват24 UAH
Русские буквы тоже надо учитывать
Ещё может BTC

Спасибо!

Comment: Вы пробовали самостоятельно решить задачу? Какие варианты вы нашли, почему они вам не подошли?

Comment: а зачем вам тогда думать о буквах. выдирайте цифры, точку и пробелы. после этого очистите переменную от пробелов

Comment: Как тогда можно сие чудо реализовать? Приведите пример пожалуйста, т.к. с регулярками особон е тслакивался(

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$str=str_replace(" ","",preg_replace("/(\\d[0-9., ]*)/","$1",$str, 1))`
Сначала получаем 1 число (включая пробелы), затем удаляем пробелы

Answer (score 2):

```
 <?php

//$value = "644.99 USD PM";
 $value = "13 644.99 Приват24 UAH";
 preg_match('!^([\d.,\s]+)?!',$value,$out);
 $value = preg_replace('![^0-9.,]!','', $out[1]);
 echo $value;
```

Comment: дополнил пример, не поленился проверить